# How read html in Python without mathjax

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to display a local html file in streamlit using python. I do not wish to display the script portion of the html. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```py
file = open("sales_impact_report.html", "r")
file1 = file.read()
st.write(file1, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

My output is this:[image]

Comment: You could search the string for `<script ` and `</script>` then delete the text between it?

Answer (score 0):

As st.write with unsafe_allow_html uses Markdown under the hood, the html should be rendered but not the script, so you shouldn't have any issues but if you still having some you can share the html so we can check it.

But in the meantime if you still need to remove the script codeblocks you could use this function:

```py
def clean_script_from_html(string):
    pattern = re.compile(r"<script[\s\S]+?/script>")
    subst = u""

    return re.sub(pattern, subst, string)
```